# How to interact with a smart contract with the web3.js library?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

i'm deploying a smart contract which contains several functions as well as properties. The ABI looks as follows:

```
[ { constant: false,
   inputs: [Array],
   name: 'vote',
   outputs: [],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
   type: 'function' },
 { constant: true,
   inputs: [Array],
   name: 'options',
   outputs: [Array],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'view',
   type: 'function' },
 { constant: true,
   inputs: [Array],
   name: 'voters',
   outputs: [Array],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'view',
   type: 'function' },
 { constant: true,
   inputs: [],
   name: 'option_amount',
   outputs: [Array],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'view',
   type: 'function' },
 { constant: false,
   inputs: [Array],
   name: 'addOption',
   outputs: [],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
   type: 'function' },
 { inputs: [],
   payable: false,
   stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
   type: 'constructor' },
 { anonymous: false,
   inputs: [Array],
   name: 'votedEvent',
   type: 'event' } ]
```

I just want to obtain the values of the properties and call some functions. However, i cannot find the right way.
So far i tried (all lead to one error or another):

```
contractInstance.options.call((err, res) => console.log(err, res))
```

*Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function*

```
contractInstance.addOption('Meeting on Saturday.')
```

*Error: invalid address*

```
contractInstance.methods.options().call().then(console.log)
```

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined*

```
    var result = contractInstance.vote(0, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1], gas: 5500000}).call((error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

*Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert*

I am using JavaScript and web3.js (0.20.2).
How do i create the `contractInstance`?

```
function deployContract(compiledContract, contractName, callback){
contractABI = getContractABI(compiledContract)
newContract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI)
byteCode = compiledContract.contracts[':'+contractName].bytecode
deployedContract = newContract.new([],{
    data: byteCode,
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
    gas: 4700000
}, function (e, contract){
      console.log(e);
      if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
            callback(newContract, contract.address)
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: I assume you're writing JavaScript? Are you using web3.js? If so, what version? How are you creating `contractInstance`? You said each gives you an error. What error does each line give you?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods is the relevant documentation. If you still have trouble after that, post your updated code including how you create `contractInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create using the same code as given below -

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545")

var Eth = require('web3-eth');
var eth = new Eth("http://localhost:8545")


//Place your ABI here

var abi = [ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_productname", "type": "string" } ], "name": "setProduct", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getProduct", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ]



//Create instance of your contract -- 
//Second argument - contract address deployed on Ganache using Web3 provider 
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x067565eaD5CAFb8C60cdd312A198c191e43Dc573")
console.log(myContract.options)
console.log(myContract.methods)


// Call the function on smart contract
//A sample setProduct() takes one param 
myContract.methods.setProduct("testproduct-created").call()
```